# How to watch a set member in StackExchange.Redis transaction

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

How do I implement the following Redis code with SE.redis?

```
watch inventory:
sismember inventory: itemA
multi
zadd market: 100 itemA
srem inventory: itemA
exec
unwatch
```

I had tried to use Transaction.AddCondition(), but SE.redis does not have a condition to watch set member changes.

Comment: I have exactly the same question, did you find a solution !!?